# Implementations of multiple conditions in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the below condition to check in which I have to check two conditions that is

1) ABSClassificationScheme = Clearing State

2) and if the first condition matches then only check the second condition that is cfStateId is accpt_novated_sw , Clearing Complete and manual_novated that is cfStateId should have one of these three values  then in that case it should print true

so I have come up with this below condition please advise is it correct

```
    <xsl:template match="ABSClassificationScheme[
                            . = 'Clearing State' and 
                            ../cfStateId = 'accpt_novated_sw' or ./cfStateId='Clearing Complete' or ./cfStateId='manual_novated' ]">
   <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>  
  </xsl:template>
```

but right now it is not working for Clearing Complete and manual_novated can you please advise is my above implementations correct or not

Comment: Your question is not clear. Show us an example of the XML input.

Comment: Also please clarify the second condition, as it quite unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a parent axis in your xpath:

```
../cfStateId = 'accpt_novated_sw'
```

Change it to

```
./cfStateId = 'accpt_novated_sw'
```

or you can just use(no `./` as it is the same):

```
cfStateId = 'accpt_novated_sw'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am merely guessing at this point, but if you have several *cumulative* (AND) conditions, and one or more of these conditions is made up of several *alternative* (OR) subconditions, you must put that condition in parentheses - because AND is evaluated before OR.